# Javascript to set noResize attribute for frame

Tags: javascript, resize, frame

I have a frameset like this:

```
<frameset id="main_frame" cols="20%,80%" frameborder="1">   
    <frame id="frame1" name="frame1" src="frame1.html">
    <frame id="frame2" name="frame2" src="frame2.html">
</frameset>
```

In frame 1, I have:

```
<body onload="enableNoResize()">
</body>
```

And the js function is:

```
function enableNoResize() {
    var frame = parent.frames['frame1'] || parent.document.getElementById('frame1');
    frame.noResize = "true";
}
```

When debugging using firebug or chrome, I found that, the js function was gone through but no affect. The frame is still resizable. I tested in chrome 16, firefox 8, IE 9.

How can I make it work? Is anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Probably you should just use the boolean constant `true` instead of the string value `"true"`.

Comment: thank you ! but I tried both. it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it, but please try:

```
frame.setAttribute('noResize', true);
```

Comment: perhaps you're forgetting something. Frameset has setAttribute() but frame doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If the frameset is in browser's top.window, try `top.window` instead of `parent`.